# Finding the number of integer triangles.

Tags: combinatorics

> The number of integer isosceles or equilateral triangles none of whose
>   sides exceed 4 must be?

I get the following triplets. I made cases and solved.

$(1,1,2),(2,2,4),(1,1,1),(2,2,1),(3,3,1),(4,4,1),(2,2,2),(3,3,2),(4,4,2),(2,2,3),(3,3,3), (4,4,3), (4,4,4),(3,3,4)$.

That is equal to $14$ triplets but answer given is $12$. I can't seem to figure out how.

Comment: $(1,1,2){{{}}}$?

Comment: Similarly, $(2,2,4)$ is out.

Comment: Why @lulu ....?

Comment: why @LordSharktheUnknown?..

Comment: Draw those two triangles and you will see the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

hint: you must Control if the inequalities $$a+b>c,b+c>a$$ and $$a+c>b$$ are fulfilled

Comment: the triangle inequality must be fulfilled! and thank you for the $-1$

Comment: and $$1+1=2$$ and $$2+2=4$$ are no triangles

Comment: equality is allowed in triangle inequality?

Comment: i think no, this is not a real triangle with area=0

Comment: happy new year 2018 with many triangles!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Same to you :).

Comment: I am unable to understand why exactly 1,1,2 are wrong?

Comment: Wikipedia says equality is allowed in triangle inequality.

Comment: in this Point lies Wikipedia

Comment: it depends on your definition

Comment: @Abcd please try to *draw* "triangles" with sides **1 1 2** and **2 2 4**.

Comment: we say it is a degenerate triangle